# Trouble comparing two strings

Tags: javascript

I have a code with a list of words. I'd like the user to guess the first letter of a randomly generated word. I'd like to check their guess by comparing what they've typed into inputone to the first letter. However, when I try to compare both strings, it never works. I tried other solutions people have proposed and none have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
startBtn = document.querySelector('.mybutton')
clueText = document.querySelector('.clue-text')
interiorOne = document.querySelector('#interior-one')


const wordList = [{
  word: "Grand",
  hint: "Something large"
},
{
  word: "Drank",
  hint: "An act of consuming liquids"
},
}
]

a = document.getElementById("inputone");
b = document.getElementById("inputtwo");
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);
let firstLetter = (random, wordList[random].word.slice(0, 1));
a.onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === 1) {
    console.log(a.value);
    b.focus();
  }
}


b.onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === 1) {
    console.log(b.value);
  }
}

startBtn.onclick = function() {
  startBtn.innerHTML = "Submit"
  console.log(random, wordList[random].word);
  clueText.innerHTML = wordList[random].hint;
  let firstLetter = (random, wordList[random].word.slice(0, 1));
  let secondLetter = (random, wordList[random].word.slice(-1));
  console.log(firstLetter);
  console.log(secondLetter);
  a.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if (firstLetter == a.value) {
      console.log('Correct!')
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <input id="inputone" type="text" class="exterior-letters" maxlength="1">
</div>
<div id="clue-text" class="clue-text"></div>
<div>
  <button class="mybutton">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If all you are checking is the first letter, one could just use a character comparison.  Also, I'm not sure why you are checking the length of the string as exactly 1, although you would want to make sure the string was of length at least 1.  Then you could just compare the first characters of each string.

Comment: Welcome! If this is the actual code you are using, you have an error in your JS. This may be your issue.

Comment: The exact way you want your UI to behave is not clear, but it looks like you want to perform the first-letter comparison inside your `startBtn.onclick` function. In that case, the second call to `a.addEventListener` in `startBtn.onclick` is unnecessary. You want to move the comparison `if` statement directly into the `startBtn.onclick` function.

Comment: Hello. That is what I had initially (no second add event). I moved the `'if' statement into the function and it does not work either.

Comment: I just removed the extra curly brace in `wordlist` and  all the `b` references since there is no `inputtwo` thus `b` is `null`... and it worked.  Keep in mind 1) you have to click the start button first 2) you have to input a capital 'G' or 'D' for the match to work and 3) It'll print 'Correct!' in the console twice if you use the `shift` key to capitalize since that'll be 2 `keyup` events in the `a` input.


working code here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-williamson-4prnqh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: If your question is about comparation of strings, remove all non necessary code and cleanup the code only your first doubt. After that, create a second question in stackoverflow if you need more help. To help you, we need a very simple example with your doubt and your example contain a lot of erros not connected with the question.